# How to change version of Mobile App in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to change the version of my application but when I am changing the version and version name I am getting an error: **"Build Failed: Xamarin.Android does not support running the previous version.  Please ensure your solution builds before running or debugging it."**. When I change the version name to 1.8.2 the error will occur. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: This error can be generated within Visual Studio when you attempt to Run your app when there are build errors. Visual Studio will attempt to instead run the "previous[ly built] version", which is something that we do not currently support.
Make sure that your project builds without any errors, then attempt to Run your app again.

Comment: The app doesn't have error I checked 0 warnings, 0 Errors, 0 messages

Comment: @Arvindraja yes I can deploy it too no error found

Comment: when I build this shows up "========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========="

Comment: Your build showing 0 succeeded. :)

Comment: Have you tried Rebuilding?

Comment: @Arvindraja but no error

Comment: @MichaelO.Y. I tried clean and rebuild still nothing

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by Arvindraja, Visual Studio will prompt to deploy the previously built version if there were build errors. In the screenshot you've posted, you're showing no app icon. Perhaps that is causing this issue?

Go through the build output and see what the output says. At some point, there should be a mention of "Build failed", or similar.